# How to customize oxypolt pie chart in xamarin.android?

Tags: android, charts, xamarin, xamarin.android, oxyplot

My code for simple oxyplot pie chart is this

```
        var plotView = new PlotView (this);
        plotView.Model = PieViewModel();

        this.AddContentView (plotView,
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));

        public PlotModel PieViewModel()
        {
            var modelP1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Pie Sample1" };
            dynamic seriesP1 = new PieSeries { StrokeThickness = 2.0, InsideLabelPosition = 0.8, AngleSpan = 360, StartAngle = 0 };
            seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Africa", 1030) { IsExploded = false, Fill = OxyColors.PaleVioletRed });
            seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Americas", 929) { IsExploded = true });
            seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Asia", 4157) { IsExploded = true });
            seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Europe", 739) { IsExploded = true });
            seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Oceania", 35) { IsExploded = true });
            modelP1.Series.Add(seriesP1);


            return modelP1;
        }
```

Now i want to customize this chart like highchart(Pie chart )

Like this:http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

How can i do this need your help?

Note: I need this chart for xamarin.android and xamarin.IOS

Thanks